# Hiding Cognito user registration behind an API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I want to use Cognito for user authentication which should work globally in internet. I also want to limit the access to user registration to a set of IP addresses. The easiest way would be use the API Gateway (which we will have anyway) and limit the access via a policy. But the registration endpoint would still be there visible to the public, wouldn't it?

How can I protect the registration endpoint and limit its exposure?